# What methods are there to to regain sanity?

Tags: dont-starve

As the game progresses, my sanity disappears. Usually slowly, but often times quite rapidly.  Try as I might, I can't seem to find a method of regaining sanity in a sustainable manner.

Picking flowers seems to return a miniscule amount of sanity. But I can't seem to find enough to really make a dent in the sanity bar.

What other methods are there to regain sanity?

Comment: So, do you mean in-game or real-life? I've definitely played games where this applies...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to regain sanity. Excluding the Hallucination-killing ones, that require you to lose sanity due to the Insanity aura, here are some powerful ways that let you recover quickly:

- Sleep in a [Tent](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Tent) (+50 Sanity)
- Sleep in a [Straw roll](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Straw_Roll) or [Fur roll](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Fur_Roll) (+33)
- Repair a [Relic](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Relic) (+20)

These are quite easy to do, and more powerful than any food-eating or flower-picking method.

Anyway, for a complete list of Sanity recovering methods you can head to the [Sanity](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Sanity) page on the wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  This game is so much more intricate than I first thought.

Answer (score 2):

Sleeping using a straw/fur roll or using a tent increases sanity by a significant amount. Eating candy or (most) food from the crock pot also increases sanity a bit.
For more detailed information you should go to http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Sanity.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a garland out of 11 petals and it will slowly increase the sanity

Answer (score 1):

Flowers can be quite useful if butterflies are captured, I suggest:

1. Make a bug net (1x twig, 4x silk, 1x rope)
2. Catch lots of butterflies (they spawn from flowers during the day)
3. Make a flower garden by planting the living butterflies
4. Catch more butterflies spawning from your flower garden
5. Plant some butterflies and (roughly) pick the same amount of flowers (to keep your flower garden from shrinking)
6. Repeat ad infinitum

During this process I suggest you keep your sanity up using alternative methods so that you can grow your butterfly farm faster and don't waste flowers. Alternative methods to keep up your sanity, include:

- Sleep on a straw/fur roll or in a tent
- Be Wilson and shave your beard (hopefully it's not winter)
- Don't wander out when it's dark
- When sanity starts dropping, stay away from the shadow creatures that you "see", staying near to them will only decrease sanity faster

This whole process can become quite intricate and involved, so it's easy to become distract and forget the first rule... Don't Starve!

Answer (score -1):

You can also make a fire it may seem a little bit long but not just at night if your sanity goes too low I suggest you make a fire pit and you just refil it when your sanity gets low and try to go right next to it and slowly but surely you will regain sanity easy
1 Make a fire (pit if you can)
2 Stand by it.

Comment: This only works as Willow.